# Jquery: countdown should not be reset when it goes to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Let us assume, In the home page, countdown is going to start may be from 2min 59sec, after 1min i have moved from home page to next page, here the countdown should show 1min 59sec right ?, but in my case it goes to again 2min 59sec.

I have been using the following  libraries for the countdown

http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

**Please Note:** I am not loading the pages through AJAX.

**Please let me know your views for how to show the correct updated countdown to all the pages.**

**Problems by using cookies:**

The problem is we never get current updated value. Because for instance, current countdown in 1min 5 sec, this info i am storing in a cookie, then immediately  I moved to next page, may be some other reasons, page is loaded after 55 seconds. 
The fact is, current cookie countdown value is 1min 5sec but we have to show the countdown value 10Seconds right ?

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `cookie` to store counter

Comment: Use a cookie to store the time the counter has been started, on page-load, initialize a counter from the start time.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is we never get current updated value. Because for instance, current countdown in 1min 5 sec, this info i am storing in a cookie, then immediately  I moved to next page, may be some other reasons, page is loaded after 55 seconds. 
The fact is, current cookie countdown value is 1min 5sec but we have to show the countdown value 10Seconds right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save your variable by localStorage and get it after going to next page like this:-

**Example**

```
var count =0;
if(localStorage.getItem("count"))
    count = localStorage.getItem("count");
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++count);
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);

});
timer.set({ time : 1000, autostart : true });
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is we never get current updated value. Because for instance, current countdown in 1min 5 sec, this info i am storing in a cookie, then immediately  I moved to next page, may be some other reasons, page is loaded after 55 seconds. 
The fact is, current cookie countdown value is 1min 5sec but we have to show the countdown value 10Seconds right ?

Comment: set the value every time the timer changed

Comment: How could I set the value when the page is loading loading internally ?

Comment: I have Edited my answer Check it

Comment: what is the syntax for adding minutes and seconds countdown ?

Comment: I am Saving the valuable that you are using to calculate the counter

Comment: Your answer is excellent. No doubt about that. But here I want to countdown minutes and seconds

Comment: Calculate the minute and second from your counter EX. if your `counter = 75;` Then `minutes = Math.floor(75/60)` and you `seconds = 75%60`

Answer (score 0):

set your timer value to local storage

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("current_time", timer_value);
</script>
```

get timer value in next page

```
<script>
    var timer = localStorage.getItem("current_time");
    //alert(timer);
</script>
```

Comment: cookie and localStorage, both are used for different purpose. just try by storing your timer to local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the "end time" in a cookie/localstorage, and use that value every time to calculate the timer, i.e: 30 seconds from now, if now is 12:00:00, save only the end time as 12:00:30 in a cookie/localstorage, and every time you need to calculate your timer subtract the current time to the end time you initially saved.

Comment: i believe, this should not be a correct way.because what if next page is loaded after 5min ?

Comment: The subtraction will give you a negative number and you will know that the timer has expired.